# How to differentiate macro and function in makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Since macro and function are all defined by the key word `define` and `enddef` in Makefile.

And they can be called by the key word `call` .

how to differentiate macro and function in makefile ?

Comment: What difference do you make?

Comment: There is no "difference": a macro can be considered to be just a nullary-function (a function that takes no arguments).  Maybe this article will help: https://make.mad-scientist.net/the-eval-function/  If you're not interested in the `eval` function skip down to the sections starting with *N-ary Evaluation* and read the rest about `call` etc.